# LibGDX - Virtual Button Couldn't Handle

Tags: android, libgdx

I use LG G4 for test my LibGdx games but i can not handle virtual buttons. How should i do this?

PS: I tried those methods

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
public boolean keyDown(int keycode)
public boolean keyUp(int keycode)
```

[image: virtual]

...add...

I have handle this situation [by this way](http://www.pixnbgames.com/blog/libgdx/how-to-hide-virtual-buttons-in-android-libgdx/) but now i got another problem. I get black bar on bottom of screen (where virtual buttons placed) but i get my game's input when i reopen my game. How can i clear this bar when i reopen game?

[image]

Thank you,
Utku Y.

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I got this solution...

`config.useImmersiveMode = true;`